# Adding a screen to acumatica mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, acumatica

I'm not a very saavy mobile developer and need some instructions broken down Barney-Style for me.

I'm running Acumatica 6.1 and I have installed their app from the google store. Unfortunately, the app leaves a LOT to be desired. I would like to put some new screens on our mobile app for everyone in the company. How would I go about this for all my users?

Specifically, I want an inventory screen to be added. I have an "item master" generic inquiry already built that can be used, assuming we can sort/search the inquiry results on mobile.

I tried googling this but couldn't get anywhere (the one post I saw didn't have very explicit instructions). A link to a solid guide or someone willing to post a short guide would be excellent! The xml looks doable, but I have no idea how to get this to everyone in my company all at once.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [Acumatica Mobile Framework Guide](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5dacbf34-ac82-41b4-b498-839c173f587c)? It should contain a lot of useful information on Acumatica's mobile app customization.

Comment: It says to go to: \App_Data\Mobile to find my screens. But i have no idea how to get there. My URL is silkcraftofor.acumatica.com
I go to

https://silkcraftofor.acumatica.com/App_Data/Mobile

and I get a 404 error.

Comment: Nevermind, I was trying to get to it from a browser, I'm thinking they want me to get to it server side. I'll have to email our hosts to have them upload the XML files. Your link is solid though. I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you for replying on a weekend :D